# Mostrar imagen de archivo en formulario con php

Tags: php, mysql

Espero que me podais ayudar
Estoy intentando mostrar archivo subido a una carpeta con php. Tengo una tabla con datos que se introducen con un formulario en la bases de datos. Los datos de la tabla se pueden editar según ID. Cuando edito una fila todo sale correcto y se edita sin problemas excepto el documento que trato de subir, que sube a una carpeta del servidor pero cuando subo el archivo y actualizo me dice que falta el ID. Me gustaría que ese archivo (el nombre, se mostrase y se pudiese abrir.

Os dejo el código:
este es el archivo upload.php

```
<?php

class  Media {

  public $imageInfo;
  public $fileName;
  public $fileType;
  public $fileTempPath;
  //Este es el destino del upload
  public $docsPath = '/home/dj9m2gz2/inventario-vi.viessmannes.es/uploads/docs';

  public $errors = array();
  public $upload_errors = array(
    0 => 'El archivo ha subido correctamente',
    1 => 'El archivo excede el peso permitido',
    2 => 'El archivo ha subido parcialmente',
    3 => 'El archivo no ha subido',
  );
  public$upload_extensions = array(
   'gif',
   'jpg',
   'jpeg',
   'png',
   'pdf',
  );
  public function file_ext($filename){
     $ext = strtolower(substr( $filename, strrpos( $filename, '.' ) + 1 ) );
     if(in_array($ext, $this->upload_extensions)){
       return true;
     }
   }

  public function upload($file)
  {
    if(!$file || empty($file) || !is_array($file)):
      $this->errors[] = "Ningún archivo subido.";
      return false;
    elseif($file['error'] != 0):
      $this->errors[] = $this->upload_errors[$file['error']];
      return false;
    elseif(!$this->file_ext($file['name'])):
      $this->errors[] = 'Formato de archivo incorrecto ';
      return false;
    else:
      $this->imageInfo = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
      $this->fileName  = basename($file['name']);
      $this->fileType  = $this->imageInfo['mime'];
      $this->fileTempPath = $file['tmp_name'];
     return true;
    endif;

  }

 public function process(){

    if(!empty($this->errors)):
      return false;
    elseif(empty($this->fileName) || empty($this->fileTempPath)):
      $this->errors[] = "La ubicación del archivo no esta disponible.";
      return false;
    elseif(!is_writable($this->productPath)):
      $this->errors[] = $this->productPath." Debe tener permisos de escritura!!!.";
      return false;
    elseif(file_exists($this->productPath."/".$this->fileName)):
      $this->errors[] = "El archivo {$this->fileName} realmente existe.";
      return false;
    else:
     return true;
    endif;
 }

  /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
 /* Function for Process docs 
 /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
  public function process_docs(){
    if(!empty($this->errors)){
        return false;
      }
    if(empty($this->fileName) || empty($this->fileTempPath)){
        $this->errors[] = "La ubicación del archivo no se encuenta disponible.";
        return false;
      }

    if(!is_writable($this->docsPath)){
        $this->errors[] = $this->docsPath." Debe tener permisos de escritura!!!.";
        return false;
      }

    if(file_exists($this->docsPath."/".$this->fileName)){
      $this->errors[] = "El archivo {$this->fileName} ya existe.";
      return false;
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($this->fileTempPath,$this->docsPath.'/'.$this->fileName))
    {

      if($this->insert_media()){
        unset($this->fileTempPath);
        return true;
      }

    } else {

      $this->errors[] = "Error en la carga del archivo.";
      return false;
    }

  }
}

?>
```

Este es el archivo php que se llama edit_coche.php

```
    <?php
  $page_title = 'Editar Vehiculo';
  require_once('includes/load.php');
  // Checkin What level user has permission to view this page
   page_require_level(1);
?>
<?php
//update user image
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $doc = new Media();
  $co_coche = (int)$_POST['id'];
  $doc->upload($_FILES['file_upload']);
  if($doc->process_docs($coche_id)){
    $session->msg('s','La documentación fue subida al servidor.');
    redirect('edit_coche.php');
    } else{
      $session->msg('d',join($doc->errors));
      redirect('edit_coche.php');
    }
  }
?>
<?php
  $co_coche = find_by_id('coche',(int)$_GET['id']);
  $all_users = find_all('users');
  if(!$co_coche){
    $session->msg("d","Missing coche id.");
    redirect('coche.php');
  }
?>
<?php
//editar info del coche
  if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $req_fields = array('modelo','matricula','usuario');
    validate_fields($req_fields);
    if(empty($errors)){
       $id = (int)$co_coche['id'];
       $modelo = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['modelo']));
       $matricula = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['matricula']));
       $kilometrosE = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['kilometrosE']));
       $kilometrosD = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['kilometrosD']));

       $usuario = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['usuario']));
       $sql = "UPDATE coche SET modelo ='{$modelo}', matricula ='{$matricula}',kilometrosE ='{$kilometrosE}',kilometrosD ='{$kilometrosD}', user_id='{$usuario}' WHERE id='{$db->escape($id)}'";
       $result = $db->query($sql);
          if($result && $db->affected_rows() === 1){
            $session->msg('i',"Vehículo actualizado con éxito");
            redirect('edit_coche.php?id='.(int)$co_coche['id'], false);
          } else {
            $session->msg('d',' Lo sentimos pero ha habido un error y no se actualizaron los datos del vehículo.');
            redirect('edit_coche.php?id='.(int)$co_coche['id'], false);
          }
    } else {
      $session->msg("d", $errors);
      redirect('edit_coche.php?id='.(int)$co_coche['id'],false);
    }
  }
?>

<?php include_once('layouts/header.php'); ?>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12"> <?php echo display_msg($msg); ?> </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading">
        <strong>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
          Actualiza vehículo de empresa con matrícula <?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($co_coche['matricula'])); ?>
       </strong>
      </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
             <form method="post" action="edit_coche.php?id=<?php echo (int)$co_coche['id'] ?>"class="clearfix" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
             
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="modelo">Modelo coche</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="modelo" placeholder="Modelo Coche" value="<?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($co_coche['modelo'])); ?>">
            </div>
               
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="matricula">Matrícula</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="matricula" placeholder="Matrícula" value="<?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($co_coche['matricula'])); ?>"> 
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="kilometrosE">kilometros entrega</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kilometrosE" placeholder="Kilometros entrega de vehículo de empresa" value="<?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($co_coche['kilometrosE'])); ?>">
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="kilometrosD">kilometros devolución</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kilometrosD" placeholder="Kilometros devolución de vehículo de empresa" value="<?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($co_coche['kilometrosD'])); ?>">
            </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="usuario">Usuarios</label>   
                    <select class="form-control" name="usuario">
                      <option value="">Usuarios</option>
                    <?php  foreach ($all_users as $users): ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo (int)$users['id']; ?>" <?php if($co_coche['user_id'] === $users['id']): echo "selected"; endif; ?> >
                       <?php echo remove_junk($users['name']); ?></option>
                   <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                 </div>
        <!----Image--->         
      <div class="panel-body">   
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
          <span> Seleccionar documento</span>
           <p></p>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img class="img-circle img-size-2" src="uploads/docs/<?php echo $co_coche['image'];?>" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="file_upload" multiple="multiple" class="btn btn-default btn-file"/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="coche_id" value="<?php echo $co_coche['id'];?>">
                 <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Subir Documento</button>
              </div>
             
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>   
            <div class="form-group clearfix">
              <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar</button>
              <a href="coche.php" class="btn btn-danger">Volver</a>
            </div>    
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 <?php include_once('layouts/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Podrías indicar exactamente cuál es el mensaje de error, para tener al menos una idea de por dónde empezar a revisar? En el código tienes mensajes de error, dinos cuál de ellos es el que se está mostrando. Si no es ninguno de ellos, agrega a la pregunta el mensaje de error que estás recibiendo.

Comment: Hola A. Cedano, lo primero de todo gracias por tu respuesta. El mensaje de error es "Missing coche id"

Comment: Bien. Veo que tienes un lío de métodos. Declaras el form con un método POST y al mismo tiempo intentas mandar el id del coche en la URL (lo que sería un método GET). Si vas a usar POST entonces pon el id del coche en un input del form, no en la URL. Dicho eso, verifica cuando recibes los datos que el id del coche no es nulo o vacío. Tu código es demasiado ingenuo en ese sentido. Me refiero a que no deberías asumir que una variable tiene datos porque sí. No sé si me explico.

Comment: El id del coche no es nulo ni está vacío cuando algún dato en el formulario se actualiza sin problemas, el que me da problemas es el campo de adjuntar el documento que da el error de missing coche id. Tengo puesto el id del coche en un input del form, está en la parte de adjuntar.

Comment: A ver. El mensaje `Missing coche id` está en esta parte de tu código: `$co_coche = find_by_id('coche',(int)$_GET['id']);
  $all_users = find_all('users');
  if(!$co_coche){
    $session->msg("d","Missing coche id.");
    redirect('coche.php');
  }` El método `find_by_id` buscaría en la tabla `coche` la fila cuyo id sea igual al valor de `$_GET['id']`, pero no está encontrando nada, sea porque el valor de `$_GET['id']` está nulo o vacío o porque no existen coches con ese valor. ¿Tú depuraste `$_GET['id']` en ese punto para saber qué valor tiene? Por otra parte ...

Comment: ... no veo que tengas un `<input name="id" ...>` en tu formulario con el id del coche. Como te dije antes, tienes un lío de métodos, declaras el método del form como POST y luego pasas valores por GET en la URL del `action` del form. No sé si entiendes lo que te estoy diciendo sobre este particular.